# Pandas - Convert 2 columns with strings in binary columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel file with many columns (more than 20). in 2 consecutive columns I have a series of strings separated by the characters ", " (comma+space). I need to convert (for each column) the sequence of strings into a series of binary columns (each column has each string as its title) and contains 1 or 0 if the string in the title is present in the row.

I've tried this into the first column:

```
DA223 = DA223.join(DA223['Comorbidità'].str.replace(r',\s*', '|', regex=True).str.get_dummies())
DA223 = DA223.join(DA223['Comorbidità'].str.get_dummies(sep=r', '), rsuffix='_right')
```

where DA223 is the excel filename and Comorbidità is the column name. if I try to use the same code in the next column (named "Terapia preoperatoria") I get the following error:

```
ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['ASA'], dtype='object')
```

note: "ASA" is the name of a column

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the input, an the matching expected output. See specific details on [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](//stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/16343464). [Do not use images of data or code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/16343464).

Comment: What do you want to happen when the column names overlap?  In the two lines above, if you run the second line only `DA223 = DA223.join(DA223['Comorbidità'].str.get_dummies(sep=r', '), rsuffix='_right')`, you could change the rsuffix to be the name of the original column.  If you run this line only, then no suffix is appended to the end of the columns (assuming none of the strings are already columns).  Running again would then add `'_right'` to the end of the column names, and a third time will repeat the columns with `'_right'` appended.  Using this line only should give your desired result.

Comment: Why using `join` for a replacement? I think you should create new columns so you can keep track of what you are doing.